# Additional data when writing in binary file python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I'm trying to dump a string message into a binary file using python pickle, but when I'm reading the file, it turns out that I have additional data at the beginning and the end of the file. Could you help me out to understand how to remove them?

Python code:

```
import pickle
from array import array

msgAscii = 'N Schmidt Alfred 01.07.1953 1001 M Dorfner \\\\Station_1\\PM \\\\*\\SIDEXIS \r\n'
msgAscii = msgAscii.replace(' ','\x00')
msgAsciiLength = len(msgAscii) + 2
arrayLength = [(msgAsciiLength>>(8*i))&0xff for i in range(1,-1,-1)]

msgAscii = chr(arrayLength[0]) + msgAscii
msgAscii = chr(arrayLength[1]) + msgAscii
pickle.dump(msgAscii,open('sidexis.sdx', 'wb+'))
```

Hex file result

[image]

0x0D ,0x0A should be the last hex values, and 0x4A, 0x00, the first 2 values.

Thanks!

Comment: You pickled the file. It will add a strucure around your data. If you want to write get the pure data into the file, make it bytes (by encoding or adding a `b` before the quotation mark and write it to the file without `pickle`.

Comment: You are right, it works thanks!